# Variable undefined error in HTML / JS script, mysterious

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a small idle game, and part of my struggle is to format all the numbers so they have commas in-between (for aesthetic purposes). I was successful in making my currency, Energy, have these commas, but I have a very difficult time adding other variables. I used the `num.toLocaleString();` and `num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");` methods on two separate occasions.

My js Code:

```
var energyDisp = '0';
var energy = 0;
var harvestClickAmt = 1;
var windmills = 0;
var windmillProduction = 1;
var windmillCost = 0;
var wcD = '0'; //Display for Windmill Cost
var solarPanels = 0;
 var solarProduction = 3;
var solarCost = 0;
var scD = '0'; // Display for Solar Cost
var dams = 0;
var damProduction = 20;
var damCost = 0;
var dcD = '0'; // Display for Dam Cost


function toCommas(num) {  
var c = num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
return c;

}

function harvestClick(harvestAmt) {
    energy += Math.round(harvestAmt);
    energyDisp = toCommas(energy);
    document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML = energy;
    document.getElementById('energyDisp').innerHTML = energyDisp;

}

function buyWindmill(){
windmillCost = Math.floor(40 * Math.pow(1.14,windmills));    
if(energy >= windmillCost){                                  
    windmills += 1;                                  
    energy -= windmillCost;                         
    document.getElementById('windmills').innerHTML = windmills;  
    document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML = energy;  
};
var nextCost = Math.floor(40 * Math.pow(1.14, windmills));  

};

function buySolarPanel(){
solarCost = Math.floor(600 * Math.pow(1.13,solarPanels));     
if(energy >= solarCost){                                  
    solarPanels += 1;                                  
    energy -= solarCost; 
    harvestClickAmt += 1;
    document.getElementById('solarPanels').innerHTML = solarPanels;  
    document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML = energy; 

};
var nextCost = Math.floor(600 * Math.pow(1.13, solarPanels));       
document.getElementById('solarCost').innerHTML = nextCost; 
toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
document.getElementById('harvestClickAmt').innerHTML = harvestClickAmt; 
};

function buyDam(){
damCost = Math.floor(5000 * Math.pow(1.126,dams));     
if(energy >= damCost){                                  
    dams += 1;                                  
    energy -= damCost; 
    windmillProduction *= 1.001;
    document.getElementById('dams').innerHTML = dams;  
    document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML = energy; 

};
var nextCost = Math.floor(5000 * Math.pow(1.13, dams));       
document.getElementById('damCost').innerHTML = nextCost; 
document.getElementById('damProduction').innerHTML = windmillProduction; 
};



window.setInterval(function(){

harvestClick((windmillProduction * windmills) +
(solarProduction * solarPanels) +
(damProduction * dams));
toCommas();

document.getElementById('wcD').innerHTML = windmillCost; 
    document.getElementById('scD').innerHTML = solarCost; 
    document.getElementById('dcD').innerHTML = damCost; 
    );
}, 1000);
```

My HTML:

```
    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />

     <head>
        <body>
        <button id = "harvest" onclick="harvestClick(5)"></button>
        <br />
        <span id="energyDisp">0</span> Energy
        <br />

        <button onclick="buyWindmill()">Buy Windmill</button>
        <br />
        Windmills: <span id="windmills">0</span>
        <br />
        Cost: <span id="wcD">40</span> Energy

        <br />
        <button onclick="buySolarPanel()">Buy Solar Panel</button>
        <br />
        Increases clicking production by 1 energy.
        <br />
        Solar Panels: <span id="solarPanels">0</span>
        <br />
        Cost: <span id="scD">600</span> Energy

        <br />
        <button onclick="buyDam()">Buy Dam</button>
        <br />
        Increases windmill production by 0.1% per dam.
        <br />
        Dams: <span id="dams">0</span>
        <br />
        Cost: <span id="dcD">5,000</span> Energy







        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

My problem? Well, the text in-game is not updating. I receive this error:
https://gyazo.com/c4b0df8453aa79f7db44655e7f7daf91

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at harvestClick (main.js:27)
    at main.js:79

Line 27: `document.getElementById('energy').innerHTML = energy;`

So... I would like an answer to both why I am receiving this console error, and how I can apply comma formatting to many variables at once and update them live (as the game is running).
Thank you!

Comment: The markup you've posted doesn't contain an element with `id="energy"` that would be matched by `getElementById('energy')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an element with an id of `energy`, so your call `document.getElementById('energy')` returns `null` - and when you try to access (and then assign) a property `innerHTML` of `null`, it's causing an exception.

Make sure to have an element with the id of `energy` declared or created somewhere - and if you're not sure if it'll always be there, make sure to check if the result of `document.getElementById` is null or not, e.g.

```
var energyEl = document.getElementById('energy');
if (energyEl) { 
  energyEl.innerHTML = ...
}
```

Comment: No problem - consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you and for the benefit of future readers.